# Why doesn't .html() replace everything with current value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('table').html('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<img src="default.jpg" />
</table>
```

As you see, that image is still there. Why? I've used `.html`, so this is expected result after executing this: `$('table').html('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Inspect the rendered markup and you will see the reason. "_How can I do that?_" -> Use valid markup.

Comment: Because the image isn't in the table once the initial DOM has been constructed.

Comment: because that is invalid markup (img can NOT be a child of table) - the browser "helpfully" moves the image to just BEFORE the `<table>` tag - remove the javascript and inspect DOM to see this is what is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `img` isn't inside the table as of when you call `html`, because it's not allowed to be. `<table><img ...></table>` is invalid markup; tables can only directly contain [certain table-related elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element), not `img` elements. So the browser fixes it for you by moving the `img` out of the table. (For instance: Chrome fixes it by moving the `img` to just in front of the table: `<img ...><table></table>`.)

If it were in the table in the first place, yes, calling `html` to replace the table contents would work:

```js
$('table').html('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="default.jpg" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> ...how can I select the image in this? `<img src="#" /> <table></table>` ? Actually I want to start selecting with `table` tag. like this `$('table').sibiling` ...

I don't think you can, reliably, because again the original markup was invalid and so browsers are free to do what they want to handle it. That said, Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 all seem to put the img *before* the table, so `$("selector-for-the-table").prev()` should be the `img`:

```js
var table = $('table');
table.html('<tr><td>test</td></tr>');
table.prev().remove(); // Remove the img
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<img src="default.jpg" />
</table>
```

Comment: great workaround. thank you. just for my information, can you please tell me how can I select the image in this?  `<img src="#" /> <table></table>` ? Actually I want to start selecting with `table` tag. like this `$('table').sibiling ...`

Comment: @stack: I've added a bit to the end of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMG is not a text tag. If you want to hide it, you must remove it.